# How to implement Javascript promises for 3 functions?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have 3 functions that both take their specific time to execute, then when they are all finished I need to trigger a certain function. With the following code, I am able to get the expected results with a single function but with multiple function I am failing to do it, please help me edit this code to wait for my ***3 functions*** then console the data they returned.

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) 
{
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        resolve('hello world');
    }, 2000);
});

promise.then(function(data) 
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promise.all() will take an array of promises as a parameter and wait for all promises to complete.

```
    var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve('function 1 resolved');
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve('function 2 resolved');
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
});

var promise3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        resolve('function 3 resolved');
    }, Math.random() * 10000);
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
    .then(resArr => {
        console.log(resArr)
    })
```

You can catch the error occurred in any of promise by using .catch() attached to promise.all()

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
    .then(resArr => {
        console.log(resArr)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has an inbuilt method that waits for all you promises to resolve.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

So for your case:

```
const promiseFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const promise1 = promiseFunction();
const promise2 = promiseFunction();
const promise3 = promiseFunction();

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result[0]);
    console.log(result[1]);
    console.log(result[2]);
  })
```

Result is an array of values returned from each promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code, where the function is called 3 times, and there are 2 ways you can do this and you can also see a different behavior.

```
// Function which returns a promise and resolves in 2 seconds
    const promiseFunction = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve('resolved');
        }, 2000);
      });
    };

    // Asynchronous function 1
    const asyncFunction1 = async() => {
        console.log(await promiseFunction());
        console.log(await promiseFunction());
        console.log(await promiseFunction());
    }

    // Asynchronous function 2
    const asyncFunction2 = async() => {
        let a = promiseFunction();
        let b = promiseFunction();
        let c = promiseFunction();

        console.log(await a);
        console.log(await b);
        console.log(await c);
    }
```

See the difference between
`asyncFunction1()` and `asyncFunction2()` calls

using async/await is a ES6 way, you can also do .then() chaining

```
promiseFunction().then(() => {
//function body here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can chain your promises, like so:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(1);
}).then(function(result) { 
  // result is 1
  return result * 2;
}).then(function(result) { 
  // result is 2
  return result * 2;
}).then(function(result) {
  // result is 4
  return result * 2;
});
```

To keep the results of all functions, you could have the result be an array, and push the new result to it every time. Like so:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve([0]);
}).then(function(result) { 
  result.push(1);
  return result;
}).then(function(result) { 
  result.push(2);
  return result;
}).then(function(result) {
  result.push(3);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
});
```

This will log `[0,1,2,3]`

Comment: This also does work but isn't it blocking the asynchronous nature of Javascript? So it blocks others from executing while I need them to execute then just sending respose should wait for each other

Answer (score 0):

If the promises are independent of each other then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(console.log);
```